# How to improve performance of application in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have developed an application which works on iPhone-3GS, iPhone-4, iPhone-4S.

For start up process, it take **30 seconds on iPhone-4s** , and take **50-55 seconds on iPhone-3gs**. Tested on same network.(Its not an issue related to network or internet; **In simulator it took only 5 second.**)

In this start up process, App performs several actions like deletion of old data from Database, WebService calling and inserting response data into Database. Application calls **almost 8 web service on main thread using performSelectorOnMainThread method(sequentially)**.

I am using SQLite and Compiled Query structure for insertion. I want to improve performance of application and want to reduce start up time taken by application.

Same back-end is used by Android team and they are also doing same thing. It takes 20 sec only on Galaxy note **(Team android is using Object Relational Modal to communicate with Sqlite database )**.

Is this the reason for faster performance ?

Is there anything that work same as ORM in Java for Objective-C to improve performance while dealing with Sqlite (processor specific , less time consuming)?

Comment: Any reason you're not using Core Data?

Comment: why are you add Android Tag ? this is Iphone Question?

Comment: @Ciryon We are working on same structure of internal database. And application is previously implemented using Sqlite; Now transforming from sqlite to coreData is like rebuilding application (Each and every phase uses Database). So i will have to find work-around of this problem. I hope u understood my problem.

Comment: @SamirMangroliya I did Tag Android ; if they can suggest anything related to ORM in Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is you should not be doing network operations (web service calls) on the main thread.  That should be done on background threads.  I don't know enough about using SQLite directly but with CoreData you can make "database" updates on background threads and just use the main thread for merging the two `ManagedObjectContexts`.

I imagine moving your WS calls to background threads (AFNetworking is a great framework btw), that you will see lots of improvement.

One example I have is a web-service based app that gets 7000 records from a SQL Server DB and creates an NSArray (data comes in as JSON) and that process takes 7-10 seconds.  I further minimize the impact on the user by doing my auto-authentication process at the same time.

30 seconds is too long to have the user wait on something IMO.

Comment: @EIJay What if i want to improve on SQLite part ? 
Is there any way to improve process of Insertion of Data and Deletion of Previously inserted Data in Table?

Comment: Method ** performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone: ** will help me ? In which i would pass NSThread object whose Priority is very high and get maximum CPU Time to get executed...?

Comment: I don't know about SQLite.  First question there is why are you not using Core Data?  CD is faster for almost all use cases.  Secondly, read up on NSOperation, NSOperationQueue and Grand Central Dispatch.  Those are the normal native way to implement multi-threading.  Might also want to check out AFNetworking.  It uses blocks and GCD and is very efficient at making network requests in the background.

Answer (score 1):

14 best tips are available here [Best Steps to increase performance of iOS App](http://code-ios.blogspot.in/2014/12/tips-to-increase-performance-of-ios-apps.html)

In this tutorial, point 13 gives the info you required.